# Yii Framework ChildrenRequiredValidator extension

Tags: php, yii

I have used yii `ChildrenRequiredValidator` extension with my project, works wonderful.

Url for extension : http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/childrenrequiredvalidator/

I have just one problem say for example :

I have two fields `min_age` and `max_age` (`min_age` and `max_age` are not compulsory fields).
Now when user fills the `min_age` then `max_age` becomes compulsory (done by using this extension) and its works fine. But `max_filed` is showing me yii required mark by default (max_age*). 
Is there any way to remove this require mark. Does anyone used this and faced the same problem.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `echo $form->labelEx($model,'max_age');` use `echo $form->label($model,'max_age');`

The above answer is based on the assumption that you are using default crud generated code from gii.